# Need to render html content as header in Pdf export

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, pdfsharp, html-renderer

I am using **Pdfsharp** v6.0.0 library and need to render header and footer to the pdf document.

My requirement is that I need to render ``` ```` content of html as header in the pdf. I tried that using html **HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp** *v 1.5.0.6* to achieve this. I was using below code to achieve this

```
HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.HtmlContainer container = new HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.HtmlContainer();
container.SetHtml(headerHtml);
container.MaxSize = new XSize(page.Width, page.Height);
container.PerformLayout(gfx);

container.Arrange(new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height));
container.Paint(gfx);
```

however I notice that **container.MaxSize** throws error of incompatibility between *Pdfsharp* and *HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp* as Htmlrenderer expects it to be 1.3.2 v.

Can anyone please help me how to achieve this in the latest version of Pdfsharp. ?

Also any other library to render html content to pdfsharp for header and footer.?

Comment: The latest NuGet packages of HTML Renderer use PDFsharp 1.50. If you download the source code for HTML Renderer, you can make it work with PDFsharp 6.0 or 6.1.